# ¿Se puede considerar al valor de return 0 como un valor basura?

Tags: c++

Quizas sea una pregunta estupida para los mas experimentados, pero me gustaria saber que sucede con el 0 que se acostumbra a retornar cuando definimos la función main de tipo entero en C++

Comment: normalmente, se devuelve al sistema, con lo que eso un script que ejecute tu mensaje puede interpretarlo como estado de ejecucion de tu programa. En general, el 0 suele interpretarse como "bien ejecutado" o ejecucion finalizada con exito. Como tal devolver un valor en main no es "basura".

Answer (score 2):

Es un estándar:

- El valor 0 se usa cuando un programa finaliza correctamente
- El resto de valores se usan para indicar códigos de error

Y esto es así tanto en Windows como en Linux.

Esta característica es aprovechada, por ejemplo, por lenguajes de scripting (bash, batch, ...) para saber si un programa externo ha finalizado correctamente o si, en cambio, se ha producido algún tipo de error.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se utiliza return 0, se le indica al método main que el programa se ejecuto correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando ejecutas un programa, lo que sucede es que el sistema operativo lo carga en memoria y comienza su ejecución como un proceso en el sistema. Se le asigna un identificador de proceso, que se apunta en una tabla (la tabla de procesos del SO) y tiene un estado.

El programa, al finalizar, debe indicar al SO si su ejecución tuvo errores o fue correcta, y esto se hace devolviendo un valor numérico al sistema.

En este sentido, lo común en un sistema cualquiera (Windows, Linux, Mac) es que el código 0 signifique que no hubo errores, mientras que cualquier otro número representa un código de error del programa, para que el usuario sepa por qué falló mirando la documentación proporcionada por el desarrollador de la aplicación, aunque puede ser de otra forma.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    string nombreFichero = leerNombreFichero();
    if (!ficheroExiste(nombreFichero)) return -1;    // Hubo errores

    // ... Trabajamos con el fichero

    return 0;    // No hubo errores durante la ejecución del programa
}
```

Por tanto, es muy importante devolver un 0 al finalizar el `main` de tu programa, para poder hacerle saber al sistema operativo que no hubo errores.

En el C más laxo, llegar a la llave que cierra el bloque de código del `main` es equivalente a devolver un 0 al sistema, y como apunta [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion) también en C++. En cualquier caso, no devolver un 0 (o un código de error) es una mala práctica, y en los nuevos estándares no solo se desaconseja, sino que se considera un error de programación.

Ten en cuenta que lo que acabo de explicar solo tiene efecto cuando se devuelve un valor desde la función `main` al sistema operativo. Devolver un valor desde una función cualquiera al `main` o a otra función no tiene más significado que el que quieras darle internamente durante el desarrollo, pero no indica nada al sistema operativo.

Si en algún punto de tu programa te encuentras con un fallo y necesitas cerrar tu programa y devolver un valor al sistema operativo, pero no estás en el `main`, puedes hacerlo mediante la función `exit`, o bien puedes lanzar un objeto con la palabra clave `throw`.

También, en la biblioteca estándar `cstdlib` tienes las macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` (que se suele expandir al número 0, pero no tiene por qué) y `EXIT_FAILURE`, para no devolver números literales, ya que puede no funcionar en algunos sistemas, si estos interpretan el 0 como error, por ejemplo.

Comment: C++ tampoco requiere de un `return 0` explícito... si la función `main` no tiene un return, el compilador añadirá un `return 0`. Aunque ya puestos, sería preferible usar `return EXIT_SUCCESS` a `return 0`. Esta macro la puedes encontrar en la librería `cstdlib`